# About Removing a cookie in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

How can i make a cookie removed while someone clicks the logout button?

Here is the code which i used but didn't work through:

```
<?php
setcookie('name','value',time()-600, '/', '', 0);
?>
```

Since I am not that much expert in PHP. Any Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['name'])) {
    unset($_COOKIE['name']);
    setcookie('name', null, -1, '/');
}
```

Comment: Oh Snap!  I can't even upvote :D

Comment: @Aadarsha welcome. You should mark is as answer :)

Comment: Stll 5 min remaining to Tick :D